# Database design for an online quiz

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I am designing an online math quiz for a college project and having some trouble with designing my database. 
The basic idea of the website is as follows:
A teacher, once registered may log in and add questions to their account. They can choose between making the questions multiple choice OR true or false. They can also choose between making their questions public or private. (If they choose to make the questions public, other teachers may view the questions.)
At any time the teacher may create a quiz for their students using the questions in their private bank and / or questions from the public bank. Each question may be used in multiple quizzes.
The idea is that the students will later log in and do the quiz; their answers are stored and the teacher can generate reports and check how the students did individually / highest and lowest scoring questions etc.

I am having some trouble deciding how to store the quizzes and questions which I hope somebody may be able to help me with.
So far I have the following:

‘Question’ table with attributes: **QuestionID**, SubjectArea, Concept, QuestionText, TeacherID, QuestionType, PublicYorN

‘MCQuestions’ table with attributes: **QuestionID**, AnsA, AnsB, AnsC, AnsD, AnsE, CorrectAns

‘TorFQuestions’ table with attributes: **QuestionID**, CorrectAns

‘Quiz’ table with attributes: **QuizID**, CreationDate, TeacherID

I think I then need another table as follows:
‘QuizQuestions’ and the only attributes will be **QuizID, QuestionID** which together make a concatenated primary key.

I feel like I should have a separate table to store answers to questions and I'm not sure if I need to separate true or false questions and multiple choice questions as I have done above.

(Obviously there are other tables containing user data etc. but this is the part I’m concerned with.)
Any advice / input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A simple yet flexible design would be something like this:

1. **Questions** table (id, text, correct answer id, all the other question related data)
2. **Answers** table (id, question id text, all the other answer related data)
3. **Quiz** table (id, text, all the other quiz related data)
4. **Quiz questions** table (quiz id, question id, question display order, other related data such as question weight might also be added)
5. **Quiz results** table (quiz id, question id, answer id, user id, all the other related data such as date of answer and such).

Answer (score 0):

I think my only input to this open ended question is:

Combine MCQuestions and TorF Questions to have a different format. Answers table has 4 cols. QID, AnswerID,answer,Correct Y/N.

Then a true or false question has 2 rows - eg. QID=888, AID=1,Ans=TRUE,true. Next row is QID=888, AID=2,Ans=FALSE,false.

Multiple choice has several - so which is the bright yellowy thing? QID=889, AID=3,Ans=Moon,false. QID=889, AID=4,Ans=Sun,true. QID=889, AID=5,Ans=Mars,false.

Then you grab a list of answers and can populate a set of radio buttons with the QID and AID values. Then you are matching integers in your code rather than long text strings which will need to be passed around for matching. Might make it a bit easier in case of special chars in the answers or whatever and you're matching the quiz results to a unique key.

Apart from that minor change it's difficult to help without knowing any other constraints...
Nick