# Database Schema for Questions and Answers of a Survey

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I want to build up a database and stuck creating tables for Questions and Answers. We have a one-to-many relationship here since one Answertype can be valid for many Questions. Like Questions1 to 20 can have the answers not good, i do not care, good.

Let us get precise. I have this kind of data:

Questions:

```
Question |TimeStamp|AnswerType|GermanLabel           |EnglishLabel
variable1|2019-2-2 |         1|Wie geht es ihnen     |How are you?
variable2|2019-2-2 |         1|Wie gut fahren sie Rad|How good can you cycle
variable3|2019-4-3 |         2|Wie alt sind sie      |How old are you?
```

Answers:

```
Answertype: 1
Timestamp: 2019-3-4
Values | EnglishLabel         | German Label
1      | almost always untrue |...
2      | often untrue         |...
3      | sometimes true       |...
4      | often true           |...
5      | alomost always true  |...

Ansertype: 2
Timestemp: 2018-4-2
Values | EnglishLabel        | German Label
1      | 25 years or younger |...
2      | 26 years to 34 years|...
3      | older than 34 years |...
```

What I have tried yet was to create a database schema for this and this looks like this:

[image]

But I would have to set up langague_value1 columns for each language that I have. Anyone who has a better idea than this and can help me get a proper schema?

Comment: This seems to have normalization issues all over the place. I would avoid columns for each language. That is known as repeating groups and violates 1NF. Consider how painful this would be if you added a new language. You also seem to be missing a parent table like Survey here. This really needs a major overhaul to accommodate what you need.

Comment: This is the same type of questions: multiple choice. You don't need different types here. Check my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34493645/3094533) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54445027/3094533).